(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
I'm working on a Node.js project, and I'm encountering some warnings in my application. I'd like to trace where these warnings are originating from in my code. I've read that using the --trace-warnings flag can help with this, but I'm unsure how to apply it correctly.
Running my application with the following command:
node --trace-warnings
However, the warning message didn't show any stack trace pointing to the origin of the warning.

Try adding
process.on('warning', (warning) => {
console.warn("warning stacktrace - " + warning.stack)
});

Can you share the full command line you're using and output you're getting
